# Celery task type error says there is extra arguments at runnig tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I have two celery tasks:

```
@shared_task
def start_scrapy(book_id, link, site, end_page=None, start_page=1):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(MainSpider, book=book, link=link, site=site, end_page=end_page, start_page=start_page)
    process.start()

@sahred_task
def find():
...
```

the problem is with the first task I'm calling the first task two times in my serializer create method The first time it's working fine but in the second call I get a TypeError

the create method:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        book_id = validated_data.get('book_id')
        site = validated_data.get('site')
        feghahat_link = validated_data.get('feghahat_link')
        maktabeh_link = validated_data.get('maktabeh_link')
        start = validated_data.get('start')
        book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
        validated_data.update({'title': book.title, 'volume_number': book.volume_number})
        task_chain = chain(
            start_scrapy.s(book_id=book_id, link=feghahat_link, site='es', start_page=start),
            start_scrapy.s(book_id=book_id, link=maktabeh_link, site='is', start_page=start),
            find.s(book_id, site)
        )
        task_chain()
        return validated_data
```

and the traceback:

```
[2023-09-06 19:53:55,762: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task extractor.crawler.start_scrapy[f918e091-f30c-48e3-8da5-ef4c43448559] raised unexpected: TypeError('start_scrapy() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mostafa/Projects/BookExtractor/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 539, in trace_task
    _chsig.apply_async(
  File "/home/mostafa/Projects/BookExtractor/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 400, in apply_async
    return _apply(args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/home/mostafa/Projects/BookExtractor/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 559, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: start_scrapy() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

I'm calling the same function for the second time with the same argument count but the error says something different!

thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution the `si()` method is used to create an immutable signature (i.e. one that does not receive data from a previous task), while. `s()` relies on the data returned by the two previous tasks.

Comment: You can mark your post as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's identation error so please check it

Comment: What do you mean? can you explain more?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).